# Using an API function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following code, how can I use the *`getUser()`* function in [ArrowChat Javascript API](http://www.arrowchat.com/documentation/?p=getuser) to retrieve the User's avatar path and replace *img-no-avatar.gif*?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
        var elem=document.createElement("img"); 
        elem.src= "/press/chat/admin/images/img-no-avatar.gif"; 
        elem.height="32"; 
        elem.width="32"; 
        document.getElementById("chattab_inner").appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have to include a file and do it pretty much exactly like the documentation says.

Comment: @adeneo What file? Can you give me an example? Where in the documentation does it say that?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this API but from a cursory glance at the userDocs i guess...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {    
        jqac.arrowchat.getUser('5','useravatarpath');
    }

   function useravatarpath(data) {
       var elem = document.createElement("elem");  

       if(data.a !== 'itsJavaScriptSoProbablyUndefined') {
           elem.src=data.a;
       }
       else {
           elem.src= "/press/chat/admin/images/img-no-avatar.gif;
       }    

       elem.height="32"; elem.width="32"; 

       // this bit i dont have time for now...
       document.getElementById("chattab_inner").appendChild(elem);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This would be closer to working if the argument to createElement was 'img' instead of 'elem,' since createElement takes an HTML tag name.